How to remove unused libraries from a visual studio solution
Writing my first vb.net VS2022 application involved a lot of experimentation while learning, adding then (only in a few cases) removing packages to the project. In the end, the \bin\debug folder contains a huge number of dlls which I'm sure I don't need. I was surprised to see the same files are also in the \Release folder. For example at one time I tried implementing "user-secrets" but then gave up after learning it doesn't do what I thought, by now I can't even remember where I typed in the user secret stuff, or if I deleted them, But there is a "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll" in the \release folder, which I assumed is more minimal collection, and files such as .pdb are not needed if there is no debugging.
I see that the .vbproj file has a lot of <PackageReference Include=... lines which correspond to the many packages.
Using "Remove unused references" reduced the number of these lines but the number of dlls and other stuff such as .pdb & .json files in the \release folder did not change.
There have been a lot of questions about this and a number of tools are mentioned in the answers. Alas, all of the threads are old and refer to VS 2010 or at best 2013.
Is there a up-to-date method or tool that can help with this clean up?
Else I will have to remove the dlls one at at time and test all the programs features to see what happens. Or perhaps deleting the <PackageReference Include=... lines one by one will remove the unnecessary dlls? Either way testing all the features of the program will take for ever, so the right tool will be best.

Regarding the issue of redundant DLL files in VB.NET projects in Visual Studio 2022, you can try the following suggestions:
1: I recommend using the "Clean Solution" command first to delete all files in the \bin and \obj folders. This will delete all generated DLL and EXE files. You can then rebuild the solution and only the currently referenced DLL files will appear in the \bin folder.
2: The .pdb file is a program database file that contains debugging information. If you don't need debugging information, you can set "Debug Information" to "None" in the "Build" tab of the project properties. This will prevent the .pdb file from being generated.

Thanks Cody. I found the CLEAN SOLUTION and ran it. It seems to help. However, there are still a few dlls left. I will experiment to see if I can drop any of then in the running release version on another pc, but should I expect that they all need to go with for the release version?

I recommend making sure you understand the purpose of each DLL file and whether they actually contribute to the running of your project before attempting to delete them.

Thanks Cody; that is the ideal approach but to look up these obscure packages for and "end-user" programmer like myself is difficult.  To begin I imagine the description (assuming I know where to find it) would contain much technical detail that puts it beyond easy reach. If you have any suggestions I'd like to hear it for future use.
